# Evaluate $\int\int_Ge^{y\over x+y}dxdy$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\int\int_Ge^{y\over x+y}dxdy$ where G is the triangle enclosed by $x+y=1$, x axis and y axis.
My attempt:
let $u=x+y$, $v=y$, $|J|=1$
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{-x+1}e^{y\over x+y}dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{v\over u}dvdu$$

But still I couldn't figure out this.

Comment: In this triangle, $u \ge v$ so you'd want the $v$ integral to go from $0$ to $u$.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the substitution
$$x=r\cos^2\phi,\quad y=r\sin^2\phi,
$$
with $|J|=r\sin2\phi $, which results in

$$
\int\int_Ge^{y\over x+y}dxdy=\int_0^1 dr\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\sin^2\phi}r\sin2\phi\; d\phi\\ 
\stackrel{\sin^2\phi\mapsto u}=\int_0^1 rdr\int_0^{1}e^udu=\frac {e-1}{2}.
$$